# WPF 4: MergedDictionaries don't seem to work any more

Tags: wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

I have the below block of XAML

```
'BaseStyles.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DataGrid.Generic.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Forms that reference this work in design-time, but not in run time.
If my form references ShinyBlue.xaml or DataGrid.Generic.xaml directly, that style sheet works.

**EDIT**

If I paste this directly into the form, it works correctly. Appearently the problem somehow has to do with my wrapper.

Broken

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../BaseStyles.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Works

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DataGrid.Generic.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine for me in WPF 4... can you provide a stripped down version of your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including your whole path from namespace to filename:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/[YourDll];component/[YourLocation]/ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
```

Where [YourDll] is the name of your project, and [YourLocation] is the location where the ResourceDictionary resides in your dll.